# "Any open subset of the reals is a countable union of disjoint open intervals". Do we need the axiom of choice to prove this?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, axiom-of-choice

I was reading Wilcox and Myers' *"Introduction to Lebesgue Integration and Fourier Series"* (Dover). On p.18, the authors try to prove that every non-empty open subset $G$ of the reals can be expressed uniquely as a countable union of pairwise disjoint open intervals. Their proof is quite similar to the one in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2108832) or the one in Steven Krantz's *"A Guide to Topology"* (MAA). So, I guess this is a rather usual proof.

At some point, the authors have shown that when $G$ is bounded, $G$ can be written as a disjoint union of non-empty open intervals $\cup_{x\in G}I_x$, where either $I_x\cap I_y=\phi$ or $I_x=I_y$ for any $x,y\in G$. Then they write:

> That this collection is countable follows from the fact that one can choose a rational number in each $I_x$ **(using the axiom of choice)**, and the disjointness of the intervals guarantees that no duplication will occur in the choice of rationals.

**Why do we need the axiom of choice?** If we denote $I_x=(a_x,b_x)$ and define
\begin{align}
n_x&=\left\lceil\frac1{b_x-a_x}\right\rceil+1,\\
q_x&=\min\left\{\frac{j}{n_x}\in I_x:\ j\in\mathbb Z\right\},
\end{align}
doesn't it suffice to pick $q_x$ as a representative of $I_x$? What am I missing?

Comment: No, we do not need the axiom of choice. We also do not need in this case to choose representatives (the rational number in $I_x$ mentioned above), but it doesn't matter anyway, because as you say one can explicitly pick a rational in that case, if need be.

Comment: Yes, there are ways to show this without choice and yours is one of them.  I suspect choice is invoked for the purpose of having to avoid explicitly write down such a formula.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo If we don't pick representatives, how do we prove that the collection of $I_x$s is countable?

Comment: All I meant is that you know you can associate a rational to each interval in each case, you do not need to go through the trouble of making it explicit. Or you can do this: Fix one of the intervals $I_x$. Define a map with domain $\mathbb Q$ by sending a rational not in the union of the $I_y$ to $I_x$, and a rational in the union to the unique $I_z$ it belongs to. This map is onto from $\mathbb Q$ to the family of intervals $I_y$. On abstract grounds, without invoking choice, if there is an onto map from a countable set to a set $Y$, then $Y$ is countable.

Comment: (Yes, I admit it is like pulling at straws to say that I am not really picking representatives.)

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Oh, you are right. Thanks. I am too used to the definition of countability using injection.